# Unity Cannot find Constructor of partial class

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a problem whereby I have a WCF service reference and wish to inject it into MVC controllers in a client. This works fine when I don't want to specify parameters, but I have since added username and password credentials to the service so these have to be set like so:

```
MyServiceRef.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
MyServiceRef.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

I decided to try use Unity to handle the username and password by creating a partial class of my service reference with constructor with 2 strings as parameters for username and pwd, and one for isTest (Bool).

```
public partial class ProductMasterServiceClientClient
 {
       public ProductMasterServiceClientClient(string username, string password, bool test)
        {
            ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
            ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
        }
    }
```

and setup Unity like so:

```
container.RegisterType<IProductMasterServiceClient, ProductMasterServiceClientClient>(new InjectionConstructor(new InjectionProperty("username", "test"),new InjectionProperty("password", "password"), new InjectionProperty("test", true)));
```

But it doesnt work! I get the following error for some reason :(

```
The type com.luzern.co40.web.pm.wsProductMasterService.ProductMasterServiceClientClient does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (InjectionProperty, InjectionProperty, InjectionProperty).
```

Anyone any idea why its not working for me? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this format:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer().RegisterType<ProductMasterServiceClientClient>(
    new InjectionConstructor(username, password, test));
```

Answer (score 4):

You question is not WCF related, it is a Unity related.
I added some samples that might help you to create a class with parameters.

**Register Instance samples**

This will register an existing class instance to the container, anyone that will resolve for ILogger, will get  the same instance.

```
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ILogger), logger);
```

**Register Type samples:**

Register a type and class, on each Resolve and new instance will be created.

```
container.RegisterType<ISession, Session>();
```

In order to register a singleton class, any Resolve will receive the same single EventAggregator class use a life time manager:

```
container.RegisterType<ILogger, Logger>(new     ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

•   This is a specific Lifetime manager that creates a single instance of the registered type in the container; in general there are other options for Lifetime managers

**Examples on register and resolve:**

When you create a class and want to DI the container itself to the class upon construction, you have 2 ways to do it:

1. Inject the container in constructor and save it as a private member:
   We register (this example its singleton and constructor takes 2 parameters):
   _container.RegisterType(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

The class constructor is:

```
 public SessionProvider(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container; //private IUnityContainer member
    }
```

When we resolve, pass the parameter to constructor as DependecyOverride:

```
 _sessionProvider = _container.Resolve<ISessionProvider>(new DependencyOverride<IUnityContainer>(_container));
```

**Additional way to use the container and DI:**
If we don’t want to pass parameter to constructor, we can DI them using the [Dependency] attribute.
This will create a new Session class on each resolve

```
container.RegisterType<ISession, Session>();
```

Instead of having a Session(IUnityContainer container) constructor, we set attribute in class:

```
[Dependency]
public IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }
```

This way, every time the container creates new object, it will set the Container property upon construction without passing it as parameter in the Resolve<>
So we don’t need to declare a constructor, the container will instantiate a class and set the container property upon instantiation. The problem is that it must be public.